# Why do these aligned equations pop to the right?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}%voor Aboxed
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\overrightarrow{a_{G'_1}} = \overrightarrow{a_{G'_2}} = \overrightarrow{a_{G'}}\\
\centerline\text{met }\overrightarrow{a_{G'_1}} &=
\overrightarrow{\alpha_1}\times(\overrightarrow{r_G}-\overrightarrow{r_E}) +
\overrightarrow{\alpha_2}\times (\overrightarrow{v_{G,1}'}-\overrightarrow{v_E'}) + \overrightarrow{\omega_2}\times (\overrightarrow{v_{G,1}'}-\overrightarrow{v_{F,1}'})\\ & \Downarrow \overrightarrow{v_{F,1}'} = \overrightarrow{\omega_1}\times (\overrightarrow{r_F}-\overrightarrow{r_E})
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\overrightarrow{e_x'} & \overrightarrow{e_y'} & \overrightarrow{e_z'}\\
\omega_1 & 0 & 0\\l_1 & l_4 & 0\\\end{vmatrix}
\Rightarrow \text{test}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

renders

[image]

Why are they too much to the right  and how can I center them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to delete `\centerline`. It is a plain `TeX` command whose use within a `LaTeX` document is not supported. For information, `\show\centerline` returns

```
> \centerline=macro:
#1->\@@line {\hss #1\hss }.
```

Thus, in your current code, `\centerline\text{met}` causes `\centerline` to pick up `\text`
as its argument (hence the fact that you get 'met' in italics). After doing `\makeatletter`, `\show\@@line` returns

```
->\hb@xt@ \hsize .
```

which is a `LaTeX` kernel abbreviation for `\hbox to \hsize`. Hence, your equations are preceded by a hbox of width `\hsize`, which shoves them to the right. Once `\centerline` is removed, your equations will be centered, but you may need to edit your question if the result is not exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Though this may answers the question it looks more like a comment. Why don’t you expand it a little and add some information why the `\centerline` causes problems and how the fixed code will look like …

Comment: @Tobi, do you know why `\centerline` messes up `align`? I don't ;-)

Comment: Me too (otherwise I’d said that) … but showing the fixed code, would be nice ;-)

Comment: @daleif `\centerline` makes a box to the current `\hsize` and just dumps it 'here' (no `\leavevmode` so can be in vertical mode). As such, it will mess up lots of things :-)

Comment: @Tobi --- since others have offered improved versions of the code, I have expanded my answer by giving details of the effects cause by `\centerline`.

Answer (score 4):

No my bad, Ian is right it is the `\centerline`.

That being said, I think I'd use

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &&\overrightarrow{a_{G'_1}} &= \overrightarrow{a_{G'_2}} =
  \overrightarrow{a_{G'}}
  \\
  &&\text{met }\overrightarrow{a_{G'_1}} &=
  \overrightarrow{\alpha_1}\times(\overrightarrow{r_G}-\overrightarrow{r_E})
  + \overrightarrow{\alpha_2}\times
  (\overrightarrow{v_{G,1}'}-\overrightarrow{v_E'}) +
  \overrightarrow{\omega_2}\times
  (\overrightarrow{v_{G,1}'}-\overrightarrow{v_{F,1}'})
  \\
  \ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow]
  && \overrightarrow{v_{F,1}'} &=
  \overrightarrow{\omega_1}\times
  (\overrightarrow{r_F}-\overrightarrow{r_E}) =
  \begin{vmatrix}
    \overrightarrow{e_x'} & \overrightarrow{e_y'} &
    \overrightarrow{e_z'}
    \\
    \omega_1 & 0 & 0
    \\
    l_1 & l_4 & 0
    \\
  \end{vmatrix}
  \Rightarrow \text{test}
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of what these appropriate `&`'s would look like?

Comment: Regarding your vectors, is it really necessary to add the arrow over the entire name? Why not use `\overrightarrow{e}_x'` instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\overrightarrow{a_{G'_1}} &= \overrightarrow{a_{G'_2}} = \overrightarrow{a_{G'}}\\
\text{met }\overrightarrow{a_{G'_1}} &= \overrightarrow{\alpha_1}\times(\overrightarrow{r_G}-\overrightarrow{r_E}) + 
    \overrightarrow{\alpha_2}\times (\overrightarrow{v_{G,1}'}-\overrightarrow{v_E'}) + 
    \overrightarrow{\omega_2}\times (\overrightarrow{v_{G,1}'}-\overrightarrow{v_{F,1}'})\\
    &\Downarrow \\
    &\overrightarrow{v_{F,1}'} = \overrightarrow{\omega_1}\times (\overrightarrow{r_F}-\overrightarrow{r_E})\\
   &=
\begin{vmatrix}
\overrightarrow{e_x'} & \overrightarrow{e_y'} & \overrightarrow{e_z'}
\omega_1 & 0 & 0\\l_1 & l_4 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
\Rightarrow \text{test}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]